# Triggering custom validation in Rails on form submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a form where data's being submitted to model guess.

```
<%= form_for(@guess) do |f| %>
```

The form is a bunch of checkboxes and I want to ensure that at least 2 of the 6 are checked.

Someone helped me with  this custom validation which I put in my Guess model

```
validates_inclusion_of :check_box_count, :in => 2..2, :message => "Two checkboxes should be ticked"

...

private 


def check_box_count
  [secondanswer_chambersapp, secondanswer_drafting, secondanswer_letter,
  secondanswer_interview, secondanswer_solicitor, secondanswer_barrister
  ].select{|x| x }.count
end
```

However, I don't understand how I can trigger this method on submission of the form from the views.  This is what the whole form looks like.  I've looked at 6.2 in the rails guides but it's too confusing for my simple newbie brain... http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#performing-custom-validations

**Can you suggest how I can link the submission of the form with the triggering of that validation method?**

```
<%= form_for(@guess) do |f| %>
  <% if @guess.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@guess.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this guess from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @guess.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>


<div class="field">
    <%= f.label(:secondanswer_chambersapp, "Chambers app") %>
    <%= f.select:secondanswer_chambersapp, 1..6 %> </br>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label(:secondanswer_drafting, "Drafting") %>
    <%= f.select :secondanswer_drafting, 1..6 %> </br>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
     <%= f.label(:secondanswer_interview, "Interview") %>
    <%= f.select :secondanswer_interview, 1..6 %> </br>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label(:secondanswer_letter, "Client Letter") %>
    <%= f.select:secondanswer_letter, 1..6 %> </br>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label(:secondanswer_barrister, "Barrister's exam") %>
    <%= f.select:secondanswer_barrister, 1..6 %> </br>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label(:secondanswer_solicitor, "Solicitor's exam") %>
    <%= f.select:secondanswer_solicitor, 1..6 %> </br>
    </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Model validation occurs when you attempt to save the record. In your controller, the method that handles the data after form submission should at some point call @guess.save. This is when the model runs through the validations. The simplest logic looks like:

```
def create
  @guess = Guess.new(params[:guess])
  if @guess.save # Model validations are run
    redirect_to guesses_url # Validations passed
  else
    render 'new' # Validations did not pass
  end
end
```

Comment: so is it the fact that the attribute is mentioned in the validation method that allows it to validate the same attribute in the form? Otherwise, I don't see how they're linked, because the name of the validation method can be anything...

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a custom `validate` method within the model which is called before saving

```
validate :checkboxes_have_enough_checked

private
def checkboxes_have_enough_checked
  [:secondanswer_chambersapp, 
   :secondanswer_drafting, 
   :secondanswer_letter,
   :secondanswer_interview, 
   :secondanswer_solicitor, 
   :secondanswer_barrister
  ].each do |attr|
    errors.add(attr, "At least 2 need to be checked!") if self.send(attr).to_i < 2
  end
end
```

If errors exist, the model will be unable to save. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-methods for details.